# Solve for $m,n\in\mathbb{N} : 2^m - 2^n = 112$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Solve for $m,n\in\mathbb{N} : 2^m - 2^n = 112$.

My try: $2^n(2^{m-n} -1)=112$.
How do I find the values of $m$ and $n$? I encountered this mid-way of solving a question about sets.

Comment: Try working on 112 - can you write it in the form of $2^k - P$? can u find a k where P is in the form of $2^l$?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$$\underbrace{(2^n)}_{\text{even}}\underbrace{( 2^{m-n}-1)}_{\text{odd}}=112=\underbrace{2^4}_{\text{even}}\times \underbrace{7}_{\text{odd}}$$

Thus, $$2^n=2^4 \implies \color{blue}{n=4}$$ and $$2^{m-4}-1=7 \implies 2^{m-4}=2^3 \implies \color{blue}{m=7}$$

Answer (score 3):

Hint. Note that $m>n\geq 1$ and
$$2^n\cdot (2^{m-n} -1)=112=2^4\cdot 7.$$